# how to render gridviewbuilder's last element in the middle

Tags: flutter, gridview

[image]

i am using gridview.builder to list these icons with crossaxiscount of 3 i want to display the icons of 2nd row in the middle(add spacing before tv icon so both icon shift to the middle)

```
GridView.builder(
                                        itemCount: state.productList.length,
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        gridDelegate:
                                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                                childAspectRatio: 2),
                                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                          return Container(
                                            child: FlatButton(
                                              child: Image.asset(_icons[i]),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                _productListBloc.add(
                                                    ItemTapProductListEvent(
                                                        state.productList[i]));
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }),
```

Comment: Grid views are built to behave like that. You can't shift a row in the middle. If you have a fixed set of icons that will never change, you can use a column and two rows individually to achieve what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) for customised grid layout.

Comment: hope this works:
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          crossAxisCount: 6,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Image.asset(''),
              ),
            );
          },
          staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
            return StaggeredTile.count(index > 3 ? 2 : 3, 1);
          },
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        )

Comment: Sorry, my purpose is to show an example how you can use a widget to achieve your goal, not just writing down the exact answer.